# how to check my azure search quota usage?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

For storage and VM, I can check the current quota usage by following powershell command:
Get-AzureRmStorageUsage
Get-AzureRmVMUsage

Is there similar thing for Azure Search? Either via powershell or Portal is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to monitor usage on portal, you could also get it via [Service Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-service-statistics).

The `Service Statistics` request is constructed using `HTTP GET` and returns from Azure Search the current usage and limits of the following properties.

```
GET https://[service name].search.windows.net/servicestats?api-version=[api-version]
Content-Type: application/json  
api-key: [admin key]
```

> how many S2 or S3 services I can created on a give region?

You can create multiple services within a subscription. Each one can be provisioned at a specific tier. You're limited only by the number of services allowed at each tier. For example, you could create up to 12 services at the Basic tier and another 12 services at the S1 tier within the same subscription. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity).

[image]

Comment: Regarding the S2 or S3 services quota, the reason why I asked the question is because when I tried to create s2 or s3 instance on some regions, I got this error: [{"code":"ServiceQuotaExceeded","message":"Operation would exceed 'standard3' tier service quota. You are using 0 out of 0 'standard3' tier service quota. So I want to check the quota on some regions to make sure the service could be created successfully in our automation script.

Comment: You could request a quota increase, go to the portal and file a support issue. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quota-errors).

Comment: @Youxu, please file a support case if you want to increase your subscription limits. You will need to provide both your subscription id and the region in which you want your increase.

There isn't a way to find out how much of your quota for services you've used. The documentation lists the public limits for *most* subscriptions (you might be on a special/restricted subscription) - You are required to keep track of the number of services you've created and compare it against the public documentation

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to check your quota usage for an Azure search service, via the portal:
If you open up the overview tab for you search service, you'll be presented with something like this: (image from a search service that I've created)

[image]

This shows the quota of resources for your search service and how much of the quota has been used up.

Comment: Thanks quick reply! In addition to the quota info in your screen shot, I also want to know the quota of search service for give price tier. Say, how many S2 or S3 services I can created on a give region?

Comment: @Joey Cai has provided the complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity

By using above url if you know what is your service plan then you can see the limits